# DataOutputSteam is throwing me a 'java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream'?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to make a Request to a WebService from an android application, using HttpUrlConnection. But sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not.

When I try sending this value:

JSON value

```
 {"Calle":"Calle Pérez 105","DetalleDireccion":"","HoraPartida":"May 18, 2014 9:17:10 AM","Numero":0,"PuntoPartidaLat":18.477295994621315,"PuntoPartidaLon":-69.93638522922993,"Sector":"Main Sector"}
```

I got an "unexpected end of stream" Exception in the DataOutputStream close function.

Here is my code:

```
DataOutputStream printout;
// String json;
byte[] bytes;
DataInputStream input;

URL serverUrl = null;
try {
    serverUrl = new URL(Config.APP_SERVER_URL + URL);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    ...
} 

bytes = json.getBytes();
try {

    httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
    httpCon.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", tokenType + " "+ accessToken);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    printout = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
    printout.writeBytes(json);
    printout.flush();
    printout.close();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It might not relate to your problem: You don't want to use a *DataOutputStream* instance. This is a binary, rather proprietary format. The correct way is to convert the JSON string into a byte array using the UTF-8 encoding and then write it directly to the connection's output stream.

Comment: A further problem in your code is that you convert the JSON string to a byte array using a default encoding. You then use the length of the array to set the content length. However, you apply the *DataOutputStream* in a way where the string is written in ASCII mode (writeBytes doesn't use an encoding; it discards the high bits). So you might have mismatch between the announced and the effective content length.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution with the following changes:

- It gets rid of the *DataOutputStream*, which is certainly the wrong thing to use.
- It correctly sets and delivers the content length.
- It doesn't depend on any defaults regarding the encoding, but explicitly sets UTF-8 in two places.

Try it:

```
// String json;

URL serverUrl = null;
try {
    serverUrl = new URL(Config.APP_SERVER_URL + URL);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    ...
} 

try {
    byte[] bytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");

    httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
    httpCon.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", tokenType + " "+ accessToken);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream os = httpCon.getOutputStream();
    os.write(bytes);
    os.close();

    ...
}
```

Comment: I literally love you, the problem was happening when the string included accented characters like 'í' but with your approach works like a charm.

Comment: @Laggel: could that be due to encoding problems? For example if a multibyte encoding such as UTF-8 is used then accented characters will typically ytake up more than 1 byte, and then the length of the bytes vs number of characters does not match any more.

Comment: Yes, that's why the length needs to be taken after encoding it as UTF-8.

Comment: Also for anybody else, you can't have `setChunkedStreamingMode(0)` set, or it won't work right.

Answer (score 1):

From the oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#flush%28%29). We know that flush method of DataOutputStream calls the flush method of the underlying output stream. If you look at the URLConnection class in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream%28%29) it says that every subclass of URLConnection must have this method overridden. If you see the HttpUrlConnection [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) we see that flush method is not overridden. It could be one of the reasons for your problem.